# How do I mark an answer as correct?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to this forum and have asked two technical related questions. I've received answers that are sound, credible and extremely helpful. I'd like to note the answers as correct and/or provide positive reviews for the persons that provided answers but cannot find where to post the information!

Comment: +1 for being sooou honest! :]

Comment: ... but it's not a forum.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe one way is to give the answer giver a tick on their questions where they speak as this improves their reputation on the site, which in a way adds to their credibility.

Also there's a checkbox which you can select stating "this post answered my question"

Answer (score 13):

We have a [faq](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) that covers both voting, accepting answers as well as [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) which allows you to perform more complicated tasks than just asking or answering.

Since we aim to be open to all, the reputation system prevents malicious activities (whether intentional or unintentional) until you've been around a bit and learned how the controls work.

Lastly, the [about](https://apple.stackexchange.com/about) page has the most brief and friendly introduction to voting and how to accept a correct answer.

p.s. Welcome to the site!